# Compile Sample2.c file using turbo c

Tags: c

I am getting error while compiling a c file `tcc Sample2.c`. The error is:

```
Fatal crtdefs.h 40: Error directive: ERROR: Only Win32 target supported!
```

I tried compiling `Sample2.c` file. I was trying to run `Sample2.c` file. This file uses JNI to access Java methods.

```
  #include "jni.h"

  #ifdef _WIN32
  #define PATH_SEPARATOR ';'
  #else
  #define PATH_SEPARATOR ':'
  #endif

  int main() {
  JavaVMOption options[1];
 JNIEnv *env;
 JavaVM *jvm;
 JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
 long status;
 jclass cls;
 jmethodID mid;
 jint square;
 jboolean not;

 options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
  memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;
  status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

  if(status != JNI_ERR) {
  cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Sample2");

  if(cls != 0) {
     mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "intMethod", "(I)I");

     if(mid != 0) {
        square = (*env)->CallStaticIntMethod(env, cls, mid, 5);
        printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
     }

     mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "booleanMethod", "(Z)Z");

     if(mid != 0) {
        not = (*env)->CallStaticBooleanMethod(env, cls, mid, 1);
        printf("Result of booleanMethod: %d\n", not);
     }
  }

  (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
  return 0;
}
else 
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think JNI will work in MS DOS? "ERROR: Only Win32 target supported!"  seems to answer your question. And more importantly, why are you using such ancient things still?

Comment: Strong advice: don't use tools that are older than you. IOW don't use turbo c.

Comment: @Lundin I am able to call C functions in Java code using JNI. I used the command window. But i was trying the other way, calling Java functions as you see in Sample2.c file. Now i am planning to use other tools to build c and run it.

Comment: I'd recommend something like Codeblocks with gcc/mingw. Beginner-friendly yet sufficiently advanced to cover everything you need.

Comment: @Lundin I am able to compile in VS2008 command env usng cl, but now facing new link error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12

Comment: @Dan VS is not a standard C compiler and in C mode it is about as old as Turbo C. The linker error means you aren't linking the library with the code.